# JQM-How to fill href tag with json object in dynamic listview?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

Help politely requested and accepted with humble gratitude.
Please: A simple explanation/solution for a simple mind.-TIA

I've searched the internet,read,and studied for days. Throwing in the towel and asking greater minds.

Using Jquery Mobile 1.4.5, Jquery 1.9.1

1. I'm reading a json file into a listview that has the inventive id loadListview: this is working fine.
2. **Problem: I would like to add a href link based on the json item:** "page": I'm totally stumped after days of searching for the answer.

*All this is done client side in a mobile app.*

Here is the code:

```js
//json
var data = [{
    "name": "Animal1",
        "page": "page1",
        "color": "",
        "photo": "",

}, {
    "name": "Animal2",
        "page": "page2",
        "color": "",
        "photo": "",
}];

//code

var result = '';

$.each(data, function (index, value) {

  //iterate through the json object
  //how do I reference the json "page" item? (#value.page doesn't work nor does #page)
    result += '<li><a href="#?????">' + value.name + ' '+ value.color + ' ' + 'value.photo' + '</a></li>';
});
//refresh the list
$('#loadListview').html(result).listview("refresh");
```

.

```
<div data-role="content">
   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="loadListview"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the '#' character as that is only for internal page links:

```
result += '<li><a href="' + value.page + '">' + value.name + ' '+ value.color + ' ' + value.photo + '</a></li>';
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/k5n6peky/)**

Comment: <EZ/> -ezanker My bad. Should have shown an internal link.  I've edited the json to reflect my error. The link is internal not external. I want to navigate in JQM to another page. REALLY appreciate your help. Will try to see if I can figure this out from your response and then  give you credit. -Rachel

Comment: That put me on the right track! THANK YOU. I just needed to use the hash: "#page1", "#page2 in the json file. Boy, little things can mess you up. Thanks again. -Rachel